# Bufferedreader readLine () take infinite input...WHY?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

why my bufferedreader `readLine()` method take infinite input
how to solve this prolbem...if anybody find any error in program.....welcome for response

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class average {

    public static void main(String[] args){

      int j,sum=0,count=0;

      String[] input=null;
      System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases");
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      int t=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

      System.out.println(t);

       System.out.println("Enter the number of contestent and there score");
       BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       try {
         String line = stdin.readLine();
         System.out.print('\n');

         while (line != null && line.length()!= 0 ) 
             input = line.split(" ");
           } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("Something wrong happend try again"+e);
           }


        for(int i=1;i<=input.length;i++)
               sum+=Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
               System.out.println(sum);   
           int avg=sum/(Integer.parseInt(input[0]));    

        for (int i=1;i<=input.length;i++)
       {
       if(Integer.parseInt(input[i])==avg)
           count++;
      } 
    System.out.println("The number of contestent who got average marks is"+count );
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why not? What is infinite?

Answer (score 3):

```
while (line != null && line.length()!= 0 ) 
     input = line.split(" ");
```

This is an infinite loop. If `line` is not null and not empty, nothing inside the loop changes that, so it will keep looping around indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

your loop is wrong. you should call `readLine()` upon each iteration, if you really want to read all data out of the stream:

```
 while( null != ( line = stdin.readLine() ) && line.length() != 0 ) 
   input = line.split(" ");
 }
```