# My program stops responding after last input

Tags: java, loops, append, freeze, filewriter

So, I have this program which was working perfectly up until a while a go. Literally the only thing that changed is when I add "true" for boolean append on FileWriter (2nd class below).
The program runs fine up until it gets to long telefone = sc.nextLong();, then it just won't continue, neither will terminate. The console just remains blank, and I can type in whatever, it won't do anything.
When I remove the "true", and the program goes back to replacing the data in the .txt, the program works fine. But I need it to preserve the data in the file, and just add new data in.
Anyone has any ideas, please?

```
package locadoraFinal;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Principal{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Filme filme = new Filme();
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        Programa:
        for (;;) {
            if (menu.Interface() == 1) {
                CadastrarCliente:
                for (;;) {
                    System.out.println("Qual o nome do cliente?");
                    String nome = sc.nextLine();                    
                    System.out.println("Qual o endereço do cliente?");
                    String endereco = sc.nextLine();                                            
                    System.out.println("Qual o email do cliente?");
                    sc.next();
                    String email = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Insira o documento do cliente:");
                    long documento = sc.nextLong();
                    System.out.println("Qual o telefone do cliente?");
                    long telefone = sc.nextLong();
                    sc.next();
                    cliente.CadastrarCliente(nome, documento, endereco, telefone, email);
                    cliente.Salvar();                   
                    System.out.println("Gostaria de registrar outro cliente?");
                    System.out.println("S- SIM");
                    System.out.println("N- NÃO");
                    if (Character.toUpperCase(sc.next().charAt(0)) == 'N') {
                        break CadastrarCliente;
                    }else if (Character.toUpperCase(sc.next().charAt(0)) == 'S') {                      
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Opção inválida. Tente novamente.");
                    }
                }
            }else if (menu.Interface() == 2) {          
                System.out.println("Os clientes registrados são:");
                cliente.ConsultaListaClientes();
            }else if (menu.Interface() == 3) {              
                CadastrarFilme:
                    for (;;) {
                        System.out.println("Qual o título do filme?");
                        String titulo = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Qual o gênero do filme?");
                        String genero = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Qual o elenco do filme?");
                        String elenco = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Qual o diretor do filme?");
                        String diretor = sc.nextLine();                     
                        System.out.println("Qual a quantidade de cópias totais desse filme?");
                        int copiasTotais = sc.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Qual a quantidade de cópias disponíveis desse filme?");
                        int copiasDisponiveis = sc.nextInt();                               
                        filme.CadastrarFilme(titulo, genero, elenco, diretor, copiasTotais, copiasDisponiveis);
                        filme.Salvar();
                        System.out.println("Gostaria de registrar outro filme?");
                        System.out.println("S- SIM");
                        System.out.println("N- NÃO");
                        if (Character.toUpperCase(sc.next().charAt(0)) == 'N') {
                            break CadastrarFilme;
                        }else if (Character.toUpperCase(sc.next().charAt(0)) == 'S') {                      
                        }else {
                            System.out.println("Opção inválida. Tente novamente.");
                        }
                    }
            }else if (menu.Interface() == 4) {              
                System.out.println("Os filmes registrados são:");
                filme.ConsultaListaFilmes();                
            }else if (menu.Interface() == 5) {
                
            }else if (menu.Interface() == 6) {
                break Programa;
            }else {
                System.out.println("Opção inválida! Tente novamente.");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }   
}
```

```
package locadoraFinal;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cliente {
    private String codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String documento;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String email;
    
    public void CadastrarCliente(String nome, long documento, String endereco, long telefone, String email) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.documento = Long.toString(documento);
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.telefone = Long.toString(telefone);
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public String Salvar() {
        String diretorio = "C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Desktop\\LP2Teste\\clientes.txt";       
        try {           
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(diretorio, true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            File file = new File(diretorio);            
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(diretorio);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String linha = br.readLine();
            int numLinha = 0;
            while (linha != null) {
                numLinha++;
            }           
            String codigo = "0" + Integer.toString(numLinha);
            this.setCodigo(codigo);             
            pw.append(this.getCodigo() + "-" + this.getNome() + "-" + this.getDocumento() +
                    "-" + this.getEndereco() + "-" + this.getTelefone() + "-" + this.getEmail() + "\n");            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return null;
    }
    
    public String ConsultaListaClientes() {
        String diretorio = "C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Desktop\\LP2Teste\\clientes.txt";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(diretorio);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String linha = br.readLine();
            while (linha != null) {
                String[] linha2 = linha.split("-");
                System.out.println(linha);
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;        
    }
    
    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }
    public void setDocumento(long documento) {
        this.documento = Long.toString(documento);
    }
    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }
    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(long telefone) {
        this.telefone = Long.toString(telefone);
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it was working before, because it doesn't look like it isn't able to correctly read the email.

Comment: It was working fine... I haven't added any kind of formatting yet, but it ran just fine. The thing is, it would only replace the first line in the .txt file, so I just added the "true" append on FileWriter so it would write in the end of the file. Now, when I run it, it gets to the telephone input, then it just stays blank in the console.

Comment: *"it just won't continue, neither will terminate"* ... why should it do either of those? You told your program via `sc.next()` to read more input and when ignore what the user wrote. Why do you do that anyway?

Comment: I don't think you only added the append mode to the filewriter, or you didn't test the whole program prior that point, because both `sc.next()` calls are wrong and causing you issues here.

Comment: That second ```sc.next()``` is supposed to clear the last character the Scanner class gets (which is when you press Enter) whenever the user inputs numbers (regardless if it's integer, long, double...).

Comment: And still, even with a second ```sc.next()```, the program should run just fine after you pressed Enter again

Comment: I already thought that you were trying that, but made some mistakes there. You should (re-)read [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045) to understand __when__ and __how__ to do it correctly. After that your program should run at least a bit better.

Comment: _"I don't think you only added the append mode to the filewriter, or you didn't test the whole program prior that point"_... I'm not looking for approval on wheter what I said is true or not... I'm saying the program ran fine before, and it doesn't now, after just adding that small little detail

Comment: I replaced ```sc.next()``` and ```sc.nextLong()```s with ```long telephone = Long.parseLong(sc.nextLine());```. Also did the same for the ```document``` variable. Still having the same issue, after inputing the telephone number, the program simply does nothing.

Comment: Like I said, it didn't work before. Also reading a file doesn't work in your code. For "interface = 1" it only works when clientes.txt is empty. If it isn't you're getting stuck because you read one line and just work with that one line. That broken code is in `Salvar()` and `ConsultaListaClientes()`, so you need to correct both. [Hint regarding the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827300/bufferedreader-readline-take-infinite-input-why)

Comment: ```for (menu.Interface() == 1)``` is an object from a different class, not Clientes class. This program has 5 classes, and like I said 4 or 5 times, it worked before. I'm not saying that the program was top-notch and it had no flaws, I'm saying that it ran the Client Information input like it should.

Comment: *"`for (menu.Interface() == 1)` is an object from a different class, not Clientes class"* ... I didn't write it were. Have you read and understand the rest of my previous comment?